# Jquery - radiobutton and change event always return "on"

Tags: jquery

I need to edit a div content based on a user choice with a radio button interface.

This is my html:

```
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" id="account_name_type" checked="checked" value="username">
    <label for="account_name_type" id="account_name_label" class="custom_font">{{ user:username }}</label>
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="nome_cognome">                                      
            <div class="cont_input">                                    
        <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" value="{{ user:first_name }}">
            </div>

            <div class="cont_input">                            
        <input id="cognome" name="cognome" type="text" value="{{ user:last_name }}">
            </div>
```

And this is the script:

```
$("input[name='account_type']").change(function() {
    var selezionato = $("input[name='account_type']:checked").val();                                                   
    if( $.trim(selezionato) == "nome_congome" )
    {
        //var nome = $('#nome').attr('value');
        //var cognome = $('#cognome').val();
        //$('#mittente_step2').html(nome+' '+cognome);
        alert('nome_cognome');

    }
    else
    {
        //var user = $('#account_name_label').text();
        //$('#mittente_step2').html(user);
        alert('user');
    }
});
});
```

All I need to do right now is `alert` the type of choice but everytime it goes to the `else` code. 
Why my `if` doen't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
nome_cognome != nome_congome
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7phLq/1/)

```
if( $.trim(selezionato) == "nome_cognome" )
                                   ^ Here
```

Comment: great.glad to help. please accept as answer when you get a chance.

Comment: Sure, as soon as stackoverflow allow me to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selezionato = $(this).val(); // or this.value
```

assuming you want to point to the radio button currently being changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Cn7J/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("input[name='account_type']").is(':checked');){
  alert('nome_cognome');
}else{

}
```